# How can I get a page to fill the screen size?

Tags: html, css

I recently started in the world of CSS and I'm trying to apply the knowledge I've acquired with a very simple exercise that is as follows:

[image]

As you can see there are several problems that I have tried to solve and I have not been able to, I will list them to see if you can help me find where I am wrong.

1. The exercise should be displayed in its entirety in the browser window (or at least that is what I would like it to be) including a lower part that is not displayed at the moment that contains another **"article"** and the **"footer"**.
2. The **"main"** title should be centered on top of the **"section and aside"** titles and not to the side as seen at the moment.
3. Inside the **"section"** tag I have two **"article"** tags and these should be able to organize themselves dynamically dividing the space that exists inside the **"section"**, as you can see they don't do it at this time.
4. Finally, as I am learning so far, I put together in the **"style.css"** a section called **"CSS Best Practices"** but I don't know if they really are, I would like your comments on my code to correct all my errors and thus learn more.

I sent you the code of my **"index.html"** and my **"style.css"** :

```
/* -- CSS Best Practices -- */

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2;
}



/* -- Globals -- */

.container {
  max-width: 120rem; 
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

header, nav, main, section, article, aside, footer {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  /* padding: 0; */
}



/* -- Body -- */

body {
  background-color: #797572;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(-173deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.20) 0%, #000000 100%),
    linear-gradient(72deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%),
    radial-gradient(47% 102%, rgba(255,255,255,0.50) 0%, rgba(21,24,32,0.60) 120%);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}



/* -- Header -- */

header {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  height: 15rem;

  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #BCBCBC 0%, #D9D9D9 26%, #EFEFEF 49%, #E0E0E0 74%, #D3D3D3 100%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #BCBCBC 0%, #D9D9D9 26%, #EFEFEF 49%, #E0E0E0 74%, #D3D3D3 100%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.20) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.20) 150%),
    radial-gradient(at 50% 59%, rgba(255,255,255,0.30) 66%, rgba(0,0,0,0.30) 200%);
  background-blend-mode: multiply,multiply,screen;
}



/* -- Nav -- */

nav {
  margin-top: 0.1rem;

  background-image: radial-gradient(27% 185%, #F9F6F1 0%, #D7D0C5 100%);
}



/* -- Main -- */

main {
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0.1rem;

  background-color: #CDDCDC;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(at 50% 100%, rgba(255,255,255,0.50) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.50) 100%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%);
  background-blend-mode: screen, overlay;
}



/* -- Section -- */

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 1rem 0.1rem 1rem 1rem;

  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #596164 1%, #868F96 99%);
}



/* -- Article -- */

article {
  margin: 6rem 1rem 6rem 1rem;

  background:  
    linear-gradient(-180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50) 2%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50) 100%),
    radial-gradient(51% 97%, #E8E8E8 7%, #CCCCCC 97%);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}



/* -- Aside -- */

aside {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0.1rem;

  background-color: #9D9B97;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(at 50% 85%, rgba(255,255,255,0.20) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.20) 150%),
    linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0.20) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.20) 100%);
  background-blend-mode: normal, multiply;
}



/* -- Footer -- */

footer {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  height: 15rem;

  background: #989898;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 100%),
    radial-gradient(at 50% -100%, rgba(255,255,255,0.40) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.40) 270%),
    radial-gradient(at 50% 2%, rgba(255,255,255,0.20) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.20) 100%);
  background-blend-mode: normal,multiply,multiply;
}



p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 3rem;
  text-align: justify;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preload" href="../src/css/normalize.css" as="style">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="preload" href="../src/css/style.css" as="style">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="header">
            <h1>&lt;header&gt;</h1>
        </header>

        <nav class="nav">
            <h1>&lt;nav&gt;</h1>
        </nav>

            <main class="main">
                <h1>&lt;main&gt;</h1>

                <section class="section">
                    <h1>&lt;section&gt;</h1>

                    <article class="article">
                        <h1>&lt;article&gt;</h1>
                        <!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit, lacus sed hendrerit posuere, augue tellus molestie metus,
                            sed pretium erat urna non lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent venenatis quam justo,
                            eget auctor libero molestie vitae. Vivamus imperdiet, quam vel vestibulum tempus, felis dui fermentum elit,
                            ac sollicitudin eros tortor eu ex. Proin imperdiet iaculis nunc, eget ullamcorper arcu vulputate in.
                            In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas ornare sagittis lobortis. Nunc tempor consectetur neque,
                            accumsan iaculis enim tincidunt sit amet. Proin egestas ut urna eu ultricies.</p> -->
                    </article>

                    <article class="article">
                        <h1>&lt;article&gt;</h1>
                        <!-- <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit, lacus sed hendrerit posuere, augue tellus molestie metus,
                            sed pretium erat urna non lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent venenatis quam justo,
                            eget auctor libero molestie vitae. Vivamus imperdiet, quam vel vestibulum tempus, felis dui fermentum elit,
                            ac sollicitudin eros tortor eu ex. Proin imperdiet iaculis nunc, eget ullamcorper arcu vulputate in.
                            In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Maecenas ornare sagittis lobortis. Nunc tempor consectetur neque,
                            accumsan iaculis enim tincidunt sit amet. Proin egestas ut urna eu ultricies.</p> -->
                    </article>
                </section>

                <aside class="aside">
                    <h1>&lt;aside&gt;</h1>
                </aside>
            </main>

        <footer class="footer">
            <h1>&lt;footer&gt;</h1>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate your help in clearing my doubts.

I have tried to make the exercise in html and css occupy only the whole screen but it always leaves it.

Comment: Hi!  What do you mean by saying "fill the screen size"? Like `max-height: 100vh;` to limit the height or `width: 100vh` to widen the content to fit the screen width? Don't be afraid read/watch CSS tutorials or read the [MDN CSS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS), for example.

Comment: Hi! Peter, tanks for the info... I mean by this is that the page or the exercise that I did occupies the entire browser window without overflowing and I can see both the header and the footer without further pagination.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at some frameworks like http://getskeleton.com/ or https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/ instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.
Also with this you have insight of working examples to learn from.